# Stop Mysqli from logging warnings if data not found in php

Tags: php, mysqli

I am sorry if this has been answered already but I could not find anything like this question.

I have a query that I search a database to be sure an email address is not listed in it. If it's not listed then it should move on down the code. However, instead, it just keeps logging an warnings like this...

> PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/public_html/index.php on line 27

How can I stop that if nothing is found?

Here is my code...

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($res, "SELECT sup_id FROM suppressionlist WHERE sup_email = '$email'");
$tcount1 = mysqli_num_rows($result1);
if ($tcount1 != "0"){
    /* DO SOMETHING HERE BECAUSE EMAIL WAS FOUND ON LIST */
}
```

Comment: which is line 27?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code to exit your script if nothing was found and display the error message.

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($res, "SELECT sup_id FROM suppressionlist WHERE sup_email = '$email'") or die(mysqli_error($res));
$tcount1 = mysqli_num_rows($result1);
if ($tcount1 != "0"){
    //Do Something
}
```

However, I would strongly recommend to use the following code. This also allows you to do something if nothing was found. This works because `mysqli_query` returns `false` when you get an error.

```
   if ($result1 = mysqli_query($res, "SELECT sup_id FROM suppressionlist WHERE sup_email = '$email'")){
        //Do something on success
    } else {
        //Do something if mysqli_query failed
    }
```

If you don't want to use else:

```
   if ($result1 = mysqli_query($res, "SELECT sup_id FROM suppressionlist WHERE sup_email = '$email'")){
        //Do something on success
        die()
    }
    //Do something if mysqli_query failed
```

Comment: JPYamamoto thanks for the help. I will use the 2nd one because I need it to continue and not throw an error. I do have one question... Do I have to use the else {  or can I just use the if statement and it continue if failed anyway?

Comment: You can use only the if statement and write the rest of your code without the else. But you have to use the function die() or exit() at the end of your if to prevent your script from running the rest of the code. Please check my answer edited

Comment: You should also start using prepared statements with placeholders in your code - if you just started learning, learn it the secure way first! http://php.net/mysqli.prepare